# Second network card in a laptop

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, network-adapter

In order to gain more knowledge in ethical hacking through practice, I wanted to get a proper network card, because my chipset is actually not good enough :(

**Problems** are:

- Is it possible to add a second network card OUTSIDE of the laptop? because I don't think I can change it, is a laptop and as i see is "sealed" or "solded". Like an ethernet/usb connection with something like an adapter? (possibly i wanted to extract the card and use it in another computer in the future.)
- This would be useful? Or must i opt for change the computer to use a better network card?

Thanks and sorry about my english, I know it is deplorable.

Comment: If you know the word "deplorable" your English can't be :-D You don't mention what you're practicing with, but you should do a bit of research to find which adapters are compatible with your tools. The model numbers are important - I've seen situations where ACME 1234N doesn't work while ACME  1234NX works, or only ACME 1234N v1 works but not v2 or v3, or... you get the point :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for wireless, check the chipset before you buy an adapter. For example: Ralink RT8070 and RT3070 work fine with `aircrack`, Realtek RTL8812AU does not seem to work. Googling for "aircrack ng supported usb wireless adapter" or something like that will give you many sites that will give you buying advice.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to add a second network card OUTSIDE of the laptop?

Yes.

I use a Panda PUA08 USB Wireless adapter and it works just great. Using it now.

So yes, you can add an adapter, just be careful to (1) get a good adapter (the Panda Card works, and other good cards work) and (2) most likely disable your on board adapter so as not to cause conflicts.

You may be able to get a replacement network card to replace the one you.  I have done this but you need an exact replacement part